# Waiting for response from mobile app to retrieve a POST variable from a submitted form

Tags: php, forms

I am writing a mobile app to send a HTTP request every 5 seconds to check whether my variable from a submitted form is set and not empty, and if so I retrieve the data to do something.

This is how my PHP code looks like on my submit form:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["convertedValue"]) && !empty($_POST["convertedValue"])) {

    $value = $_POST["convertedValue"];

    echo "{value: $value}";
}
else{  

    echo "{value: No Value}";
}

?>
```

My question is, because my app is continuously sending requests, would the POST variable also be reset? If so, how can I save the variable such that my app can retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the POST variable would reset in each call. so you have to send the `convertedValue` via POST each time you call this script for this to work.